# When are moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, election

I read this artice : [When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-are-the-elections), but I still don't know when moderator elections are held. What does it mean when they say: "when needed"? When there are three users willing to take up the task?

Comment: I don't think there is a pre-defined date. My assumption is that when several moderators wish to step down or there is need in new moderators, the dev team raise the flag and start planning the elections.

Comment: I've made a bit of a severe edit there. Can you check if it still says what you intended to say?

Comment: @bart thanks for you edits. It's okay.

Comment: I see right now that 3 moderators are needed, but no election yet.  "moderator candidates
18
moderator positions available
3"  or maybe that was just the status of the election, and not the current status.

Comment: @nycynik where did you read this ? Thanks for information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/election/3  but since i posted that I realized that it was the status for the election, and not dynamic informaiton. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The need for an election is checked roughly once a year, at least that is what some SE employees have once said on the topic. But certain circumstances can also directly cause SE to hold an election outside of the once a year cycle.

Elections are needed if the number of moderators is too low to effectively handle all the work without overburdening the moderators. This can happen either by moderators resigning or becoming inactive, or by growth of the site. Sometimes the moderators tell SE that they need some more help, sometimes SE just looks at the growth of the site and decides  that more moderators would be useful.

Comment: About the same as what I was thinking, glad I wasn't wrong. Maybe you better mention you moderate two sites yourself, it will give more official look to your answer. :)