# Who is "The community team"?

Tags: support, election, community

The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/339911) stated:

> The community team periodically looks at the work load...

For me it's not clear who is **"community team"** for each particular SE site.

Comment: [I think this covers a lot of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349266/the-community-teams-stack-exchange-and-how-we-work-together) unless it doesn't, in which case an edit might help

Comment: What makes you think SE has staff members dedicated for each site? Did you see this written somewhere?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I'm not sure that I clearly understand you. Are you saying me that [support] question not allowed here?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you appear to have wrong info, so wonder if you saw it somewhere, in which case, the source should be corrected as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's not clear who is "community team" for each particular SE site.

The current members of the community Team are listed here in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/267099).

I don't think they have specific responsibilities for particular sites.

[JNat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/) is responsible for scheduling elections across all sites.

Answer (score 2):

CMs aren't usually assigned to a single site. In fact, every now and then a CM will check in with the local mods, and who does this varies on purpose so that mods have a chance to see a variety of names.

The exception is the international SO sites. There are a limited number of CMs who can speak each language.

Comment: Not all the international sites have a 'dedicated' CM. They used to hire CMs for that specifically and a few are still around but say japanese SO dosen't have its 'own' CM

Comment: @JourneymanGeek according to [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217) ruSO doesn't have dedicated CM as well.

Comment: Uh .I think Nicholas counts?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek nope, he was re-assigned long ago to be "Community Strategy". (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do/99341#99341))